# Exceptions C++: Catch by reference/value

Tags: c++, exception

I have a question regarding catching exceptions in C++.
Consider the following example, where we're catching by value:

```
struct baseException{};
struct derivedException : public baseException {};

void g(){
    // Bad stuff

    if(!stuff)
        throw derivedException();
    else
        throw baseException();
}

void f(){
    try{
        g();
    }
    catch(derivedException e){
        // Caught derived exc
    }
    catch(baseException){
        // Caught base exc
    }
}
```

Let's say that `baseException` is thrown. Wouldn't the compiler see that `derivedException` is a specialization of `baseException`, and therefore choose the more correct catch clause (`baseException`)?

I would agree that, if `derivedException` is thrown, and the catch clause order was reversed, slicing would happen, but I'm not really sure what would happen in this case. Why can't the compiler see it as a specialization?

I do agree it's the wrong way, and you should always catch by reference to conserve polymorphicic properties, but I'd like to know why compiler can't recognize the specialization.

Comment: " to conserve polymorfic properties" there are other reasons too - what if, for example, it threw because of bad_alloc - and now you're asking to allocate more memory?

Comment: I can't get what's your question. According to your code, if `derivedException` is thrown then `derivedException` would be caught; if `baseException` is thrown then `baseException` would be canght.

Comment: you also should catch by reference to avoid copies.

Comment: Exactly @songyuanyao. I just think the most used argument used on the internet to use catch by reference, is that catch by reference conserves polymorphic properties. But if this works, I can't see why it's such a good argument. Though I agree it's the best way, fx as  UKMonkey says - if the stack is full, there's a problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen Yes, the biggest reason is to avoid copy; for efficiency, and other issues UKMonkey mentioned.

Comment: @songyuanyao All I wanted to know - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule for catch clauses is that the **first** match is the one that's selected. Unlike overloaded functions, there is no notion of "best" match.

So in the example code, if `stuff` is false, the body for `catch(derivedException)` would be executed, because the thrown exception has type `derivedException`; if `stuff` is true, the body for `catch(baseException)` would be executed because the first catch clause doesn't match, but the second one does..

If the catch clauses were reversed, then regardless of the value of `stuff`, the body of the first catch clause (`catch(baseException)`) would be executed, because both exceptions can be caught by the base type.

Comment: I actually thought it would pick the base-catch if it was in reversed order. Thank you for that clarification!